# Overlay in Floating Menu in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

I am looking for Overlay, in Ionic Floating Menu. I have used [ionic floating menu](http://market.ionic.io/plugins/ion-floating-menu)

I am using this plugin but it's not giving me overlay.

Any suggestion or sample code would be helpful.

Regards,
Sopo

Comment: Please provide all the relevant code (HTML, CSS, Javascipt) so we can see it and help troubleshoot. Add it to a jsFiddle, if possible.

Comment: Following is the fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/jeh2k8yz/50/